# ColorFunctionScaling and OpacityFunctionScaling with values other than 0 and 1

Tags: plotting, color, opacity

I have a 3D density plot that I was able to get to look okay with setting `ColorFunctionScaling` and `OpacityFunctionScaling` to True. I know that there are other ways to view this data, but I checked the documentation and both these functions treat the minimum value as 0 and the maximum as 1. With the 3D plot, this obscures the middle. Is there a way to have it so that for example, the whole plot is scaled with opacity between 0 and 0.7?

Here is the example I am using. If possible I would also like the color function reduced to between 0 and 1/14.

```
prob1 = (E^(-2 Im[ArcTan[x, y]] - Re[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]]) Abs[x^2 + y^2])/(64 \[Pi]);

P1 = 
 DensityPlot3D[prob1, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, {z, -20, 20},
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  OpacityFunction -> Function[a, a^1.2], 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> True, OpacityFunctionScaling -> True,
  FaceGrids -> {{-1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}}, 
  Ticks -> Table[{{-20,"-20a0"}, {-10,"-10a0"}, {0, "0"}, {10,"10a0"}, {20, "20a0"}}, {i, 3}], 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

This yields the above:
[image: Density Plot Graph]

I'm looking for a way to lower the opacity of the inside of the doughnut in that same kind of exponential function I have, and I want the maximum opacity to be 0.7. The `prob1` function just takes to long to run if I add a `Maximize`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set

```
OpacityFunctionScaling -> False
```

and adjust the `OpacityFunction` to perform the scaling itself.  Since the minimum value of `prob1` is `0` and from the legend (produced by `DensityPlot3D` but not shown in the plot in the question) the maximum is about .0027, the function should read

```
OpacityFunction -> Function[a, (a/.0027)^1.2]
```

which indeed reproduces the plot in the question.  To reduce the maximum opacity to `0.7` instead of `1`, use

```
OpacityFunction -> Function[a, .7 (a/.0027)^1.2]
```

This choice does not change the plot much, but reducing the factor from `.7` to, for instance `.3` produces a very noticeable change.

[image]

How much is enough is in the eye of the beholder.  Incidentally, the scale factor, `.0027`, also can be obtained from

```
prmax = FindMaximum[prob1, {x, y, z}] // First
(* 0.00269241 *)
```